# Would it be possible to create an animation background that moves when the mouse hovers and scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, frontend

I'm wondering how to create a website like https://vos9x.com/.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fkUe.jpg)

How can I create a background animation?

What is the name of this kind of animation?

What frame work should I use?

Do you think it's possible to create it with Wordpress and the Elemtnro plugin?

Comment: Those animations are for advanced people. generally `anime.js`, `three.js`, `velicity.js` and some other JS libs are used to create those kind of animations.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you use Wordpress with Elementor you can try the Mouse Effects of Elementor that offers this functionality at some level.

https://elementor.com/help/mouse-effects-mouse-track/

Comment: This is not a *find me a link* website. Please read [answer]. This could have been eventually a comment to OP. Get enough reputation and you'll be eligible to post comments.

Comment: In your opinion or according to community rules how can I help him when the elementor has documentation for this?

Comment: Answers with only a link are not in the expected quality format for this site. Usually we provide links to 3rd party websites in comments. Or eventually after an exhaustive answer with code samples to provide more authoritative context from external documentations.